# Load a nib file to act as a custom keyboard when a UITextField is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, xib, custom-keyboard, inputview

I'm trying to load a `.xib` file to act as a custom keyboard when a textField is tapped. I'm able to show the `.xib` file (view) when the textField is tapped but I'm not sure how to communicate the buttons in the `.xib` file with the a textField in the *ViewController.swift*.

This is what I have done so far.

1. Created a single project.
2. Added a `UITextField` and created an outlet for it.

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var myField: MyTextField!
   ```
3. Created a new `.xib` file and called it `CustomView.xib`.
4. Created a new class and called it `CustomView.swift`.
5. Assigned class `CustomView.swift` to the `CustomView.xib` file.
6. Added some `UIButtons` in the `CustomView.xib` file. These will be acting as a custom-keyboard, they will show when the textField is tapped and hide when the `resignFirstResponder` method is called.
7. In the `viewDidLoad` method of the `ViewController.swift` I assigned `inputView` as follow.

   ```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var myField: MyTextField!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       let myView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil).first as? CustomView
       myField.inputView = myView
       }
   }
   ```
8. Done

When I run the app and tap on the textField the .xib file shows (see picture below), my problem is, how do I communicate the buttons with the textField in the `ViewController.swif`. In other words what I want is to show the numbers in the inputField when they are tapped.

Any suggestions? Is this how this is usually done.

Here is an image that shows the view shown when the inputField was tapped.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have 9 `UIButton`s, then consider <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + dragging an `IBAction` from all these buttons in storyboard to a *single* method such as:

```
- (IBAction)tapped:(id)sender
{
    textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%li", textView.text, (long)((UIButton*)sender).tag];
    NSLog(@"%@", textView.text);
}
```

given that `textField` is your text field, you could then append each corresponding number from your keypad (that is to say, the buttons) using the `tag` property of these buttons and the aforementioned method.

You could set the tag number for each single button in storyboard (I.e., 1 - 9, respectively).

I didn't test it using 9 buttons but did with only 2, with tag numbers 1 and 2, respectively for each buttons. The result was displaying fine in `UITextField` (I.e., `1`, `12`, `122` and so forth).

***Update (Post-comment):***

I was able to re-create this using a `nib` file containing a few buttons and a `UITextField` in *storyboard*.

The process proceeds as follows:

**1.** Create a nib with all the buttons (which you already have done).

**2.** Create a view; and under "Custom Class", re-name the class to this view (I.e., "Custom Class" -> "Class" -> "view-that-holds-the-buttons").

**3.** Wire the `IBAction`s (a total of 9 corresponding to the number of your buttons) to one *single* method as described above.

**4.** In your other view controller whose view hold the `UITextField`, load the nib using your existing method.

**5.** Add this view (from nib) as subview.

The following concerns with communication between the view (that holds the buttons along with the `IBAction` method) and the controller in which you load the `nib`:

**6.** create a `delegate` (`weak`) property.

**7.** Before you add the view (from `nib`), assign this `delegate` with the view controller (the control that loads the `nib`).

**8.** Create a protocol:

For instance:

```
protocol keypadProtocol : class
{
    func displayKeys(keystrokeObject: AnyObject)
}
```

Have the view controller that loads the `nib` conform to this protocol and implement the required method (`displayKeys`):

```
//The one that loads the nib, which also holds the UITextField
class mainViewController: UIViewController, keypadProtocol
```

So, once the buttons are tapped, the `IBAction` would be called; but instead of displaying it, we send the `sender` to our `delegate`, which is the view controller that implements the `displayKeys` method and holds the `UITextField`.

The `IBAction` would be implemented as follows:

```
@IBAction func tapped(sender: AnyObject)
{
     delegate!.displayKeys(sender)
}
```

`displayKeys` would be implemented like the following:

```
func displayKeys(keystrokeObject: AnyObject)
{
    textView.text = NSString(format: "%@%li", textView.text! ?? "", (keystrokeObject as! UIButton).tag) as String
}
```

Declaration of the `delegate` in the controller where you load the `nib` file:

```
weak var delegate : keypadProtocol?
```

Assigning the `delegate` from within the view controller where you load the `nib`:

```
keyPadView.delegate = self //keyPadView is the nib file loaded
```

---

***In reply to your second comment:***

Assumption:

We have 2 classes.

The first one is a subclass of `UIView`, which is the `xib`, that holds the buttons.
Let’s call this „KeypadView“.

The second one is the main view controller, which is associated to the controller that holds
the `UITextField` in your storyboard.
Let’s call this „MainViewController“.

***Step 2:***

Firstly, please create a new `UIView` and name it, for the sake of consistency, „KeypadView“.
Then, click on your .xib file; on the right panel, click on the third tab from the left, which is called „***Identity Inspector***“; you would see „***Custom Class -> Class***“, where you would associate this `xib` to the class you created (you need this class, in order to connect the `IBAction` for the buttons from the `xib` file to it). It would be the „KeypadView“, which is a subclass of `UIView`.

***Step 6:***

You declare this in the class („KeypadView“) that holds the buttons.

***Step 8:***

You connect this method (`IBAction`) to the aforementioned class (I.e., „KeypadView“).

Once you load the `xib` („KeypadView“) from within the „mainViewController“, set the `delegate` in „KeypadView“ to `self` (`self` is the „MainViewController“):

```
let keyPadView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil).first as? KeyPadView

keyPadView.delegate = self
self.view.addSubview(keypadView)

//you may need to re-adjust the position of the views; I will leave that to you
```

In your  „KeyPadView“ class, there should be an `IBAction` that gets called from each of the buttons:

I.e.,

```
@IBAction func tapped(sender: AnyObject)
{
    delegate!.displayKeys(sender)
}
```

Our `delegate` is the „mainViewController“, if you recall.

Since `displayKeys` is implemented in „mainViewController“, the following method would be called therein:

```
func displayKeys(keystrokeObject: AnyObject)
{
    textView.text = NSString(format: "%@%li", textView.text! ?? "", (keystrokeObject as! UIButton).tag) as String
}
```

„mainViewController“ would then display the keystrokes in its `UITextField` (I.e., `textView`).

Comment: I know how to display values from a uibutton to a textfield, my issue is that the buttons are in the .xib file and the textfield is in the main storyboard. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous post since I figured it out. Thanks a lot for your help.